# identical() Returning False and True for Identical Matrices

Tags: r

Code is at end of post.

I've been trying to troubleshoot a program to generate cyclic subgroups of GL2.  For some reason it's having issues when the generator has an element that was computed from a fraction whose decimal representation has infinitely many digits (but *only if* the elements are defined as arguments).  Even if the elements of some power of that generator are identical to the identity matrix's elements I still can't get identical() to return TRUE.

I've managed to figure out that there's some issue with how the value of the generator is actually being assigned, but I can't figure out why.  To reiterate, I know that the issue is arising out of the bit of my code that actually turns the fraction-string into a number (and I've verified this in the shell environment).  I just don't understand why this is happening, though it seems obvious that it has to do with the infinity of digits in the decimal representation.

Calling the program like `Rscript code.R 0 1/3 3 0` gives me a case where the order of the generator is infinite (when it should be equal to 2).  `Rscript code.R 0 1/2 2 0` gives me the correct subgroup with the correct order.  I also end up with the correct order when I define the generator with components {0,1/3,3,0} without all of the string manipulation.  In either case I still get a matrix whose elements are ij = 1 if i=j and ij=0 if i =/= j for even powers of the generator.  So what am I missing, here?

```
library(expm)
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

if (length(args) !=  4){
    stop("Usage: Rscript GL2_cyclic 11 12 21 22", call.=FALSE)
}

for(i in 1:length(args)){
    if(length(grep("/",args[i])) != 0){
        temp <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(args[i],"/")))
        args[i] <- temp[1]/temp[2]
    }
}

args <- as.numeric(args)

gen <- matrix(args,nrow=2,ncol=2)
id <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),nrow=2,ncol=2)

main <- function(A){
    i <- 1
    matrixlist <- list()
    if(det(A) == 0){
        stop("Matrix is not invertible", call.=FALSE)
    }
    else{
    while(!(identical(A%^%i,id))){
            matrixlist[[i]] <- A%^%i
                i <- i+1
            }
            if(identical(A%^%i,id)){
                matrixlist[[i]] <- A%^%i
            }
        print(matrixlist)
        sprintf("Order of generator = %d",i)
    }
}

main(gen)
```

Comment: Do you think you could boil this down to a small reproducible example? Ie construct a small example of creating your matrix and ID matrix where `identical` is returning FALSE and you expect it to return TRUE? (Also, it is probably because of tiny numerical differences - `all.equal` can be used to test for numeric equality with specified tolerance)

Comment: I think I see the issue, when you're rewriting the value to args, it's getting turned back into a character, this doesn't matter with 1/2, but it should matter with 1/3 as the as.character trims precision. Try creating a new, all numeric vector to store the values in.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee

The identity matrix is generated, in the script, by the statement `id <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),nrow=2,ncol=2)` and the error is easily reproduced if I process some vector of strings through `for(i in 1:length(args)){
    if(length(grep("/",args[i])) != 0){
        temp <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(args[i],"/")))
        args[i] <- temp[1]/temp[2]
    }
}

args <- as.numeric(args)

gen <- matrix(args,nrow=2,ncol=2)
`
Then `identical(gen%^%2,id)` returns false.

And wow.  Sorry about the formatting.  I have no idea why that looks like such a mess.

Comment: @Shape

I'm reassigning args by `args <- as.numeric(args)`.  This appears to be a numeric vector, when I check by adding `print(args)` after the assignment.

Comment: @Chib right, but that's only after you already trimmed precision by turning it into a character during the loop

Answer (score 2):

OK, so my initial thought (numeric precision) was off.
The reason is that `args` is a *character* vector. So when you save `temp[1]/temp[2]` (a number) back into `args`, it gets coerced to a character.

This means it'll get cut off at whatever your display width is, e.g. for me `args[2]` will be `"0.333333333333333"`. Of course when this is converted back to numeric that's the number you get, which is not the same as 1/3. (I found this out by adding a `print(args)` before the `as.numeric` to see what was happening).

So, the solution is to create a different vector - a *numeric* one - to hold the numeric values of the arguments (to prevent them from being coerced to string).

e.g.

```
# convert to numeric, suppressing warnings for fractions which won't convert
n.args <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(args))
```

Then in your loop, save the numeric value to `n.args` not `args`.

```
for(i in 1:length(args)){
    if(length(grep("/",args[i])) != 0){
        temp <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(args[i],"/")))
        n.args[i] <- temp[1]/temp[2] # <--- here
    }
}
```

In the rest of your script use `n.args` not `args.
Then it should be OK.

---

(Aside:

1. The line after the while loop seems to double up a bit with the while loop itself. I think by adjusting the start/end conditions you may be able to avoid this.
2. you are calculating `A %^% i` many times for the same `i`. For 2x2 matrices I guess this is not very expensive, but it might become so with larger ones. Consider storing `A %^% i` for each loop and then just referring to the stored value, rather than re-calculating. You already store it in `matrixlist[[i]]`, so just use that rather than `A %^% i` for subsequent calls.

e.g in `main`.

```
i <- 1
matrixlist <- list(A)
if (det(A) == 0) {
    stop("Matrix is not invertible", call.=FALSE)
} else {
    while (!identical(matrixlist[[i]], id)) {
        i = i + 1
        matrixlist[[i]] <- A %^% i
    }
    print(matrixlist)
    sprintf("Order of generator = %d", i)
}
```

Comment: alternatively, instead of doing all that string parsing to find the numbers, how about `sapply(args, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))`

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Seems to work.  Thanks.  Can't wait to see what happens when I try to modify the script to deal with fractions of irrational square roots...

Comment: In that case, numerical precision might come up. Consider `isTRUE(all.equal(x, y))` as opposed to `identical`, since it has a small tolerance (that you can modify). Also with regards to parsing these numbers from the command line, see Shape's comment. Then you could type e.g. `sqrt(2)` and R would evaluate it without you having to do more regex.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee

I'll definitely consider it.  The only reason why I haven't actually used Shape's suggestion is that I'm not really familiar with sapply.  I really have no formal training in writing code and I'm trying to work through Judson's book, so I tend to kludge things up to avoid doing calculations by hand.

Comment: @Chib read `sapply` as "Do this function for each element of args", cleaner than writing it in a for loop, and actually, if you use vapply, potentially faster

Comment: @Chib - oh, use a `for` loop if it's easier for you to understand. I meant to use `eval(parse(text=args[i]))` rather than all the `grep`ping you're currently doing.